# How to check what styles are applied to an element?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a HTML object element which is retrieved by

```js
document.getElementById()
```

Is there any way to find out what styles are applied to this element? Not just class name set in CSS attribute. What I need is similar to the style inspect feature of FireBug (FF Addons). Is this possibly done with JavaScript?

Comment: You could have a look [at this article](http://robertnyman.com/2006/04/24/get-the-rendered-style-of-an-element/).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this via [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). You can then use [`getPropertyValue()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue) to extract whatever CSS rule you are looking for, or you just iterate over all values:

```js
let element = document.getElementById("test");
let styles = window.getComputedStyle(element);

let bg = styles.getPropertyValue("background-color");
let fg = styles.getPropertyValue("color");

console.log(bg);
console.log(fg);
```

```css
div {
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" style="background: #ccc">Hello World</div>
```

Note, however, these two important quotes from the MDN:

> The returned style is a live CSSStyleDeclaration object, which updates automatically when the element's styles are changed.

And:

> The returned CSSStyleDeclaration object contains active values for CSS property longhand names. For example, border-bottom-width instead of the border-width and border shorthand property names.